# Creating a Photo Editor with Brightroom | Swift

Tags: ios, swift, image, photo, editing

The code I was shown for creating a Brightroom photo editor, that offers all of the different Brightroom features, was:

```
@IBAction func editImage(_ sender: Any) {
        guard let image = image else { return }
        let editor = Brightroom.Editor(image: image)
        present(editor.controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

This code is now out-of-date and inaccurate. Additionally, the GitHub documentation is not very thorough. Would someone please show me how I could create the editor shown in the GitHub visual examples (image editor, photo cropping, masking)?

[Brightroom Library](https://github.com/FluidGroup/Brightroom)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a Photo Editor (or, add that functionality to your app), your best bet is to go through that Brightroom code and learn how to do it.

However, if you want a quick example of presenting its built-in editor:

```
@IBAction func editImage(_ sender: Any) {

    guard let image = UIImage(named: "samplePic")
    else {
        print("Could not load image named \"samplePic\"!")
        return
    }
        
    let imageProvider: ImageProvider = ImageProvider(image: image)
    
    let editingStack = EditingStack(imageProvider: imageProvider)
    
    let controller = ClassicImageEditViewController(editingStack: editingStack)
    
    present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

---

**Edit** - *to answer question in comment...*

If you want to use this `BrightRoom` library - it's open-source. You really, *really*, ***REALLY*** need to spend time going through all of its code so you know and understand how to use it.

After a quick look, it appears the approach to saving the edited image is to render it via the editing stack class.

Here's a really simple, sample implementation...

Notes:

- `ViewController` ***must*** be in a navigation controller, as the "Classic" editor UI uses navBar buttons

  - view will turn red if it is NOT in a nav controller and print a message to the debug console
- sample code loads an image named "samplePic" from assets (replace with your image name)

  - view will turn red if it CANNOT load the image and print a message to the debug console

If we pass the above tests, we should see this (with whatever image you added):

[image]

Tapping the "Start Editing" button will **push** to the "Classic" editor controller. Tapping "Done" in the nav bar of that controller will **pop** back to this view and update the image view with the edited image.

Please keep in mind -- ***This is Sample Code Only!!!*** I wouldn't expect it to be anything close to actual production use.

```
import UIKit
import BrightroomEngine
import BrightroomUI

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var imgView = UIImageView()
    var editBtn = UIButton()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        guard let _ = self.navigationController
        else {
            print("This controller must be in a UINaviagationController !!!")
            view.backgroundColor = .red
            return
        }
        
        // replace with your image resource name
        let imgName: String = "samplePic"
        
        guard let image = UIImage(named: imgName)
        else {
            print("Could not load image named \"\(imgName)\"!")
            view.backgroundColor = .red
            return
        }

        imgView.image = image
        imgView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imgView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.95, alpha: 1.0)

        editBtn.setTitle("Start Editing", for: [])
        editBtn.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        editBtn.setTitleColor(.lightGray, for: .highlighted)
        editBtn.backgroundColor = .systemBlue

        [imgView, editBtn].forEach { v in
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview(v)
        }
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            imgView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            imgView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0),
            imgView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgView.widthAnchor),
            imgView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerYAnchor),
            
            editBtn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgView.bottomAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            editBtn.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 240.0),
            editBtn.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.centerXAnchor),

        ])
        
        editBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(editTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        
    }
    
    @objc func editTapped(_ sender: Any?) {
        
        guard let image = imgView.image
        else {
            print("Could not load image from image view!")
            return
        }
        
        let imageProvider: ImageProvider = ImageProvider(image: image)
        
        let editingStack = EditingStack(imageProvider: imageProvider)
        
        // create the "Classic" editing controller
        let controller = ClassicImageEditViewController(editingStack: editingStack)
        
        // set the closure for NavBar "Cancel" tap
        controller.handlers.didCancelEditing = { [weak self] vc in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        }
        
        // set the closure for NavBar "Done" tap
        controller.handlers.didEndEditing = { [weak self] vc, editStack in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            
            var img: UIImage!
            do {
                let r = try editStack.makeRenderer().render()
                let imgData = r.makeOptimizedForSharingData(dataType: .png)
                img = UIImage(data: imgData)
            } catch {
                print("error?", error)
            }
            if let img = img {
                self.imgView.image = img
            }
            self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
            
        }

        // push to the editing controller
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Yeah, I've been looking at the code, but I must be looking at the wrong portion or something because I didn't see something like what you provided anywhere. Also, there's no Save button once the image has been edited. How would you add that?

Comment: @ChristianW - you really need to dig into the code. However, see the **Edit** to my answer... maybe it will get you started in the right direction.

Comment: This will certainly help me get started and allow me to understand their code better. Thank you for taking the time to help me out.